# How to test availability of primaries of the "find" command and output which ones it supports?

Tags: find

I am writing a script that determines whether `find` supports the following primaries:

- iregex
- Btime
- atime
- inum with +/-

So far, I came up with this:

```
find / -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 1 -inum +0 -exec echo "ok:inum+-" \; 2>&1 | head -n 1
```

It should output "ok:inum+-" only if that primary is understood by the command.

The problem with this is that I rely on find finding matches, or else it won't output anything.

Ideally, the tested primary should not matter what it finds, and the echo should always be execuated unless the tool aborts with an error.

I realize that I could instead leave away the `-exec echo …` and check the exit code of the `find` invocation, but how would I then print the "ok:" string depending on that?

Oh, and any solution needs to be a **one-liner** per tested primary.

Comment: Using `-mindepth` is not a good start as it's not a standard one. Use `-prune` instead.

Comment: Any code can be put on one line, asking for a *one-liner* generally doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Usually, I use "-mindepth 1" so that I don't get results about the starting dir itself. I have no idea how I'd use -prune in place of it, though. Is there a way?

Comment: Sorry, `-prune` (which prunes branches of the tree) is more for `-maxdepth`. For `-mindepth 1`, it's more `find . ! -name .` or `find /path ! -path /path`. Or `find . -path './*'` or `find /path -path '/path/*'` (those can be adapted to higher values of depth with `-path '/path/*/*...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect for the presence of anything on stderr:

```
find_supports() {
  [ -z "$(find / -prune "$@" 2>&1 > /dev/null)" ]
}
```

Then:

```
if find_supports -inum +0; then...
if find_supports -exit 2; then...
if find_supports -maxdepth 1; then...
```

Beware that there are predicates that some `find` supports, but in incompatible ways between them.

For instance `-regex` expects basic regexps in BSD `find` by default while GNU `find` expects a regex flavour from some ancient version of `emacs`.

The interpretation of *suffixes* in `-mtime`/`-size` also varies across implementations.

Also, the above can't be used to test for `-depth`/`-delete`/`-mindepth` as they conflict with `-prune`. `-depth` is standard, and implementations that have `-maxdepth` also have `-mindepth`.

Comment: I appreciate the extra warnings on the quirks of various implementations. I've found that I cannot even query the version of some implementation, such as on macOS, hence why I started testing the options individually. Still, determining which regex flavor will work is going to be a challenge.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann, I'd recommand using `-E` on BSD and `-regextype posix-extended` on GNU to get EREs for both (and stick to the the POSIX ERE specification). You could also add your voice to https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=42501 to improve things in the future.